# Question about relationship between wb_motor_set_position and wb_robot_step

Tags: c, robotics, webots

I'm really new to Webots and a novice at programming. I'm currently trying to drive a robot with rotational motors along a known path using a controller in C language. I'm mainly using the wb_motor_set_position function. However, the amount the robot actually travels in the simulation seems to depend on the position I set in this function, as well as the time step. I am currently running a while loop, setting wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) and then using wb_motor_set_position. I've been reading the documentation on these, but it still doesn't seem to click to me. Does anyone know how these two functions are dependent/related to each other and how I could maybe determine the distance the robot would go with these (without using a position sensor first) - instead of my current just plug and chug method...? Thank you!

Comment: Rather than only describe your code, post it here.

Comment: For wheeled robots, it makes more sense to control them in velocity rather than in position. See https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#velocity-control for details.

Comment: I ended up changing the model for velocity control. Thanks!